Money doesnt appear on Raydium, shows in Wallet
i just recently set up my Phantom Wallet and transferred 500$ worth of ETH from my MetaMask Wallet to my Phantom Wallet. The transaction went trough, the money is in my wallet, but when I go on Raydium and connect my Phantom Wallet it says insufficient funds and my ETH doesnt show up. Any idea? Thanks in advance! J

This is not the right place for this kind of questions,
